# Is there an Echo effect for animating in blender?

Tags: rendering, video, effects, timeline, compositing-nodes

I used to be a heavy user of After Effects, I am wondering if there is a similar effect to echo in Blender. That is used for simultaneously showing a specific animation in the future and the past simultaneously.

Edit: In addition to Leanders answer below, is there a simple way to fade the transparency or change colors of the frames before and after.

Perhaps somehow linking the generator setup with the frame duplication to a transparency node?

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a function which creates a very close effect to the one you're describing.

[image: demo]

In the Properties Panel, go to the object section and under *Duplication*, select **Frames**.

Duplicates of the object in its state from the specified Start and End frame are shown on all frames. To create the echo, set a keyframe on both properties.

Then, go to the graph editor and add a *Generator* modifier to both curves. By choosing a lower offset for the *Start Frame* property you will have a span of frames which are shown.

```
Start Frame = -10 + 1 * x
End   Frame =  10 + 1 * x
```

Comment: Thank you! This was exactly what I was looking for! greatly appreciated.  Now is there a way to change the color and/or opacity, of the frames in the future or past?

Comment: @Nick I added another answer, with which's method this is possible. However it is not as straightforward as I don't know animation nodes very well. You could edit your post to include the prerequisites of changing color etc as well to receive other/more fitting answers.

Comment: I think in 2.80, it's Properties Panel > Object Panel > Instancing" - and in the Graph Editor it's Key > Add F-Curve Modifier > Generator" - that being said I cannot get to display settings for the F-Curve modifier on my Sidebar...

Answer (score 2):

#### Using Animation Nodes

You can use the [animation nodes addon](https://github.com/JacquesLucke/animation_nodes). Install it and enable it. Then, in the Nodes editor a new Node Type button will appear: the animation nodes node type.

With it we can create time offset instances and modify the material of those instances.

[image]

[image: motion trail]

I am using a vertex color *Col*, which is modified for each instance.

This is the animation nodes node tree.

[image: animation nodes tree]

I won't explain every node in detail, as they are well documented.

- On the left hand side there is a group of three nodes which

  1. get a reference to the animated object *Cube*
  2. create instances of it
  3. plug the list of instances into a loop.
- The loop receives a list of objects and a reference to the original object. The list of object will provide a reference to 1 instance on each run of the loop.
- In the loop, the fcurves for translation, rotation and scale are evaluated at a time different to the frame right now. The evaluated frame is offset -1 of the current frame per loop run. This is how the objects are offset in the 3D space. **Obviously, this doesn't account for other deformation like modifiers (armature), shapekey and other.**

Comment: Leander, thanks for the help, how would I reverse the opacity, copying what your formula is My leading frame is invisible, and my tailing frames become more and more solid. I would like to reverse that.

Comment: @Nick Switch the BSDF inputs of the Mix Node (from the shader in the first image).

Comment: cool I'll try that out, I actually threw in a reverse list between my instancer and invoke subprogram and it worked like a charm