# How Can I Achieve This "image bleed" Background Effect?

Tags: rendering, objects, shaders, effects, world

I am new to blender and I'm trying to figure out how to get objects and images to bleed onto a background.

Video E.G.: 
[Look at the background and how objects are being printed onto it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vWzs4yI4lkU&t=10s)

I accidentally did it in a project while messing with the world shaders, but at the time I did not need to do it and now I can't seem to replicate the effect.

If anyone has any ideas please share them with me!

Comment: I don't know in Blender but in some other applications it is an "Echo" effect.

Comment: See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/127612/is-there-an-echo-effect-for-animating-in-blender