# Where are the Settings for F-Curve Modifiers?

Tags: animation, modifiers, graph-editor

I tried to follow [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/127612/is-there-an-echo-effect-for-animating-in-blender), but I'm failing at seeing where the F-Curve modifier Settings are displayed. Once more, the Blender UI is failing me with its logic.

According to the Manual they should be in the [Sidebar](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/graph_editor/fcurves/modifiers.html)! No luck in either 2.79 or 2.80.

### Blender 2.79

I Went to the **Graph Editor** and selected <kbd>Key</kbd> > <kbd>Add F-Curve Modifier</kbd> > <kbd>Generator</kbd>. The Cube in my scene disappeared and where in the **Sidebar** there should have been settings, there were none:

[image]

*File for 2.79*

[image]

### Blender 2.80

Blender 2.80 is even more confusing since they redesigned the Sidebar but didn't update the Manual to match. I followed the same steps but didn't even know where to look for Settings.

*File for 2.80*

[image]

**How does one edit an F-Curve modifier?**

Answer (score 1):

They are talking about the *Graph Editor* right panel, displayed with <kbd>N</kbd>. You can click on the *Modifiers* tab, click on *Add Modifier*, choose *Generator*. Once created, as it has a Y coefficient of 1 by default, it moves your cube away, you can reduce this factor.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. So in the first link it is a duplicated cube that is offset?

Comment: It is not duplicated, it's the generator effect that pushes it away as ypu can see if you play with the modifier parameters

Answer (score 1):

My problem was that I hadn't clicked on a keyframe yet. The modifier tab didn't open if I pressed <kbd>A</kbd> to select all, but it did pop up once I clicked on an individual keyframe.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Blender 2.82.

1. Select axis on the left side
2. press <kbd>TAB</kbd> or 'right-click' -> *Toggle Channel Editability*
3. press <kbd>N</kbd>

You'll see modifiers :)