# Animation Nodes - Delay Rotation

Tags: animation-nodes

Let's say there are two cubes: A and B. The A cube is rotated by the Dope Sheet. I would like the B cube to follow the A cube rotation, but with a delay of 10 frames. Is that possible to accomplish in Animation Nodes?

Comment: Yes, with the Evaluate Fcurve node for example. [Related: Is there an Echo effect for animating in blender?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/127730/30849)

Comment: @Leander Thank you! I got my example scene working. Added **FCurves from Object**, **Get List Element** and **Evaluate FCurve** as in the example that you suggested. There seems to be one "gotcha" though: **Get List Element** uses index to select FCurve, so the whole setup will break if the order of FCurves on the object changes. Is there any way to reference FCurve in the list by name, such as "Z Euler Rotation"?